_systemNavigationAction not working iOS 17
static func jumpBackToPreviousApp() {
        guard
            let sysNavIvar = class_getInstanceVariable(UIApplication.self, "_systemNavigationAction"),
            let action = object_getIvar(UIApplication.shared, sysNavIvar) as? NSObject,
            let destinations = action.perform(#selector(getter: PrivateSelectors.destinations)).takeUnretainedValue() as? [NSNumber],
            let firstDestination = destinations.first
        else {
            return
        }
        action.perform(#selector(PrivateSelectors.sendResponseForDestination), with: firstDestination)
    }

Does anyone have a solution? it doesn't work on iOS 17 anymore
